# Find the value of $\displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{x}+2\ln{x}-2x+2}{\ln^2{x}-x\ln^2{x}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, logarithms

I have a question which askes us to find the value of the integral:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \int \limits_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{x}+2\ln{x}-2x+2}{\ln^2{x}-x\ln^2{x}} \mathrm dx$

I tried using differentiation under integral using some variable, I couldn't go any further, I even tried the substitution $\ln x=t$, it just reduces the size of integral. I divided the integral with the denominator to get $3$ separate integrals but each of them diverges. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you get substituting $ln x=t$? it seems the most natural approach,

Comment: Are you sure you've transcribed correctly? Wolfram Alpha, at least, can't find an indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions, and the value of the definite integral doesn't show up in the ISC.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have transcribed correctly, Wolfram Alpha says the value of 'definite integral is $0.415093$'.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant; assuming you trust Wolfram Alpha for a few more significant figures than that, then the value it gives doesn't show up as an expression in the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Comment: how did you get that? consider posting it as an answer?

Comment: A solution is given in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2177992

Comment: @RiverLi could you tell, how did you find that?

Comment: @MathLover I used https://approach0.xyz/search/.

Answer (score 5):

We first begin by enforcing the substitution $e^{-u} = x \, \implies -e^{-u} \, du= dx$

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x+2\ln x-2x+2}{\ln^2 x - x \ln^2 x} \, dx \stackrel{x \mapsto e^{-u}}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2} \cdot \frac{u^2-2u-2e^{-u} + 2}{e^u-1} \, du$$

Now using the fact that:
$$\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} \, dx$$
We can then compute the following Mellin transform:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \frac{x^2-2x-2e^{-x}+2}{e^x-1} \, dx=\Gamma (s) \left(2-2s \zeta (1+s) +s (1+s) \zeta (2+s)\right)$$

We are interested in the case that $s\to -1$ which gives:
$$\boxed{I=\gamma+\ln (2\pi)-2}$$

Comment: Could you please comment on the $s$-region of validity of the various formulae? The one for $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$ is for example valid for $\Re s>1$. Also about the interchange of the limit and integration at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the integral into three
\begin{align}
I=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 x+2\ln x-2x+2}{(1- x) \ln^2 x} \, dx \\
=&  \int_0^1 \underset{=\>\ln\frac\pi2}{\frac{x-1}{(x+1) \ln x}} dx +
\int_0^1 \underset{=\>\gamma}{\frac{\ln x+1-x}{(1- x) \ln x} }dx
 -2\int_0^1 \underset{=\>1-\ln2}{\frac{\ln x(1+x^2)+1-x^2}{(1-x^2) \ln^2x} }dx\\
=& \> \ln(2\pi)-2+\gamma
\end{align}