# $\int_0^1 \frac{x - 1 - x\ln(x)}{x\ln(x) - x\ln^2(x)}dx= \gamma$

Tags: integration

Prove
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \frac{x - 1 - x\ln(x)}{x\ln(x) - x\ln^2(x)}dx= \gamma
\end{equation}

where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant

I don't know where to begin with this, a hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The substitution $u=\ln x$ might be helpful because you can factor an $x$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In similar spirit to this other [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393921/find-the-value-of-displaystyle-int-limits-01-frac-ln2x2-lnx-2x2/4394015#4394015).

Enforce the substitution $x=e^{-u}$ to give

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-1-x \ln(x)}{x \ln(x)-x \ln^2 (x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \left(\frac{1}{u+1}-e^{-u}\right)\,du$$

Consider the Mellin transform
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{s-1} \left(\frac{1}{u+1}-e^{-u}\right)\,du=\pi \csc (\pi s)-\Gamma (s)$$
Which follows from the beta function (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634091/generalisation-of-an-already-generalised-integral?noredirect=1)) and definition of the gamma function respectively. Taking the limit as $s\mapsto 0$ gives the desired result of $\gamma$.

Comment: ... or, as an option, integrating by part:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u} \left(\frac{1}{u+1}-e^{-u}\right)du=\big(\ln u-\ln (1+u)-\ln u \,e^{-u}\big)\Big|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\ln u\,e^{-u}du$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Indeed, that is probably a more elementary option, but I personally like the Mellin transform method for the ability to easily generalise.

Comment: Excellent approach. +1 I had first encountered this on Quora, and man I did a lot of non rigorous stuff in that answer. Still feels bad. -_-